# Clarify the difference between input/output stream and input/output buffer

Tags: c++, c

**EDITED**

**Input stream and Input buffer**

From what I understand, when a key is pressed on the keyboard, the character go into the input stream (stdin) and get stored in the buffer. Then the scanf (in case of C) or cin(in case of C++) extracts the character from the buffer and places it in the main memory.

**Output stream and Output buffer**

Similarly, before characters are displayed on the screen, they are first stored in a buffer. Then the printf (in case of C) or cout(in case of C++) extracts the characters from the buffer (when it is full) and sends it to the output (stdout) stream.

Am I right? I've been stuck on this for quite a while now and my logic may be flawed.

Comment: In the abstract sense, a stream is any continuous source of input data or a channel for output data. Streams are not necessarily buffered (e.g. an analog transducer on GPIO pins), and buffers are just blobs of data that might not have anything to do with a stream (e.g. a bitmap's raster buffer). The Streams types in C++'s std are not necessarily buffered either.

Comment: You are basically correct for the streams used by the C and C++ Standard Libraries.

Comment: @Dai The standard input and output streams are buffered.

Comment: I'm kind of confused here. For example, people recommend to use the fgets() function instead of the gets() function when taking string as input because gets() might cause input buffer overflow. What does buffer mean in this context?

Comment: In this context, it means the array of `char` that `fgets` and `gets` read into - `fgets` provides a means of controlling how many characters are placed in the array, `gets` does not (and is a deprecated function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Side note: `scanf()` is not the function to *read* input, [see more here](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

---

Now for your question: When asking about C (and, C++), e.g., the language, you should stay within the abstract concepts the language provides. So, don't start at the keyboard, that's far outside your program.

Start here: The operating system wants to deliver some input to you. Now, your C runtime provides a *stream* of input to your code. The *stream* is an abstract concept, it just means something you can continuously read from. This stream can be buffered or unbuffered, and if it's buffered, there are different modes (fully buffered or line buffered) available. You can configure all of that.

If your stream is unbuffered, this means the operating system has to wait until your code wants to read from the input stream. By default, your standard input stream is *line buffered*, which means your C runtime accepts the input immediately and puts it into a buffer until there is a newline -- your code calling input functions will get a result from that buffer.

Conceptually the same happens with output, just the other way around. If your output stream is for example line buffered, your C runtime will fill a buffer until there is a newline and deliver that whole line to the operating system for output. If the output is unbuffered, every single character is immediately passed to the operating system.

---

Disclaimer: this is still a lot simplified, but should be enough to start with.

---

As you ask about the term "*buffer overflow*" in the comments, mentioning `gets()` -- this is about a buffer inside **your own code**. With any input function that reads more than a single value/char, you have to provide your own buffer for it to store the result to. With `gets()`, there's no way to tell the function how large this buffer is, so it will just overflow it whenever the input available is too large. This is why `gets()` is ill-defined and meanwhile removed from the language C. It has nothing to do with buffers of your C runtime that are possibly used in the implementation of the I/O streams.

Comment: Wow, that cleared a lot of chaos in my mind. So the term "buffer overflow", in case of the gets() function, applies to the size of my, let's say, character array inside the code?

Comment: yes, that's a buffer as well, you define it yourself.