# Two cins in a row, what exactly happens with whitespaces?

Tags: c++

```
cin >> name;
cin >> age;
cout << name << age;
```

What exactly is happening here if I type a string, then some whitespace and a number? For example `Something 20`. Does it read `Something` then sees the whitespace and goes okay that's the end of this first line because a whitespace terminates the reading of the string, goes to the next input and reads `20`?

But I also wanna be a bit more specific. Is it okay to say at first when I'm in the console typing `Something`, that's going into the standard input stream, then getting stored in the buffer and when I press that space it's like pressing enter? And that `Something` gets extracted and assigned to `name`? Then that `20` I type is like a whole new unrelated line because I pressed space earlier and so that gets extracted and assigned to `age`?

Comment: Did you try it? What did you observe?

Comment: Assuming the input is well formatted and complete, whitespace characters are skipped, then `name` is set from the stream, then whitespace characters are skipped, then `age` is set from the stream.  The code snippet provided has no error checking, so if the input was bad, the error would go undetected.

Comment: Not all terminals are consoles. https://superuser.com/questions/144666/what-is-the-difference-between-shell-console-and-terminal/144668#144668

Comment: Note that what you type is not a string then some white space and a number. It's just text. `cin >> name` copies text verbatim (into what might be a `string`, but the code doesn't show it), and `cin >> age`, if `age` is some sort of integer, reads text and converts it into an integer value. That might sound like nitpicking, but when you have to debug input failures you'll find it much easier if you remember that text input is just text.

Comment: This reference may be of help here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Comment: I mean I did try but I'm still a little confused because what I said kinda seems to be happening, name became something and age became 20, but I'm still a little confused because if I type "something" then enter, and then 20 and enter, the same thing happens. So it kinda seems like enter and space are doing the same thing? But like I'm still confused because according to what I know while typing stuff in the console that goes into the input stream then the buffer, so with spaces I'm not really changing that am I? The spaces just get ignored and idk "Something20" ends up in the buffer? Idk man

Comment: Yeah I'm confused idk can someone try to explain

Comment: The stream input operators try their best to get the job done :) They just need *something* to separate the string from the number. Whitespace includes end-of-lines, so to these operators a tab `'\t'`, a space `' '`, or a CR `'\r'` or a LF `'\n'` are all the same. They act as delimiters, but other than that they are skipped.

Comment: Please edit your question showing the exact type of `name` and `age`.

Answer (score 3):

## How they'll get extracted

The integer gets extracted via [std::basic_istream::operator::>>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

> Extracts values from an input stream
>
> 1-4 ) Extracts an integer value potentially skipping preceding
> whitespace. The value is stored to a given reference value.
>
> This function behaves as a FormattedInputFunction. After constructing and
> checking the sentry object, which may skip leading whitespace,
> extracts an integer value by calling std::num_get::get().

The string gets extracted via [std::basic_string::operator>>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt):

> 2 ) Behaves as a FormattedInputFunction. After constructing and
> checking the sentry object, which may skip leading whitespace, first
> clears str with str.erase(), then reads characters from is and appends
> them to str as if by str.append(1, c), until one of the following
> conditions becomes true:
>
> - N characters are read, where N is is.width() if is.width() > 0,
>   otherwise N is str.max_size()
> - the end-of-file condition occurs in the stream is
> - std::isspace(c,is.getloc()) is true for the next character c
>   in is (this whitespace character remains in the input stream).

And in [FormattedInputFunction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction):

> if ios_base::skipws flag is set on this input stream, extracts and
> discards characters from the input stream until one of the following
> becomes true:
>
> - the next available character on the input stream is not
>   a whitespace character, as tested by the std::ctype facet of the
>   locale currently imbued in this input stream. The non-whitespace
>   character is not extracted.
> - the end of the stream is reached, in which
>   case failbit and eofbit are set and if the stream is on for exceptions
>   on one of these bits, ios_base::failure is thrown.

And as stated in [Basic Input/Output](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/) from cplusplus.com:

> ...Note that the characters introduced using the keyboard are only transmitted to the
> program when the ENTER (or RETURN) key is pressed.
>
> ...
>
> ...cin extraction always considers spaces (whitespaces, tabs,
> new-line...) as terminating the value being extracted, and thus
> extracting a string means to always extract a single word, not a
> phrase or an entire sentence.

## Testing

Compiling and testing your program with leading and trailing whitespaces via MSVC-v142 compiler:

```
            AA           123             some trailing whitespaces
```

Prints out:

```
AA123
```

## Read also

Stackoverflow: [Clarify the difference between input/output stream and input/output buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51458342)

Learn cpp: [Input and output streams](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/input-and-output-io-streams/)

Comment: Tiny question um from what I know if I type something in the console that goes through the input stream and gets stored in the buffer, and only gets extracted when I press enter, so like how is >> extracting something from the input stream if what I'm extracting is stored in the buffer?

Comment: I think you're extracting from the buffer of the input stream, the input stream stores the input inside it's buffer, so reading from input stream is like saying reading from it's buffer, but I'm not advanced in C++ so I could be saying something wrong here, I'll provide some more links in the answer.

Comment: @EggedBe2 please mark your question as answered if I clarified your confusion.